# Did Deacon's prosthesis have any "special features"?

Tags: animosity, animosity-evolution

The first generation of Animata, animal-machine hybrids, was comprised of Mimi (cat), Tango (dog), and Deacon (ram). While obviously their prostheses were replacements for lost limbs, they also had "augmented" functions to facilitate the Animata becoming a new kind of order:

- Wintermute has fingers and [some kind of (ray?) gun](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2GOq.png);
- [Tango had fingers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HALdu.png) (apparently a lesser version of Wintermute's), or at least more handy claws than your average dog's;
- Mimi had a [tailtip blade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5BS7.png) and the same kind of fingers/claws as Tango;
- Deacon had... a muzzle thing?

Really, the only unusual thing we ever saw Deacon do with his prosthesis is smoke a cigarette.

[image: First-gen Animata]

We know that Mimi, Deacon and Tango were chosen due to their loyalty to Wintermute, but we also know Wintermute is the kind to do things efficiently; it would seem very out of character for her to only grant Deacon a respiratory apparatus.

Hence, is there any more information about the functionality of Deacon's prosthesis (by the writers perhaps?), or was it just "for show"?

Comment: You don't think him smoking a cigarette and talking is bad-ass enough already?

Comment: @Valorum bad-ass isn't what Wintermute is into and the talking certainly isn't her doing

Comment: Haven't read this - can the other animals also talk? I see the little one on the bedpost is talking, but Deacon's voice uses black word balloons, implying something about the sound of the voice. From this one panel, I'd be inclined to say the prosthesis is where his voice is coming from.

Comment: @RDFozz yep - the premise is that _"One day, the Animals woke up. They started thinking. They started talking. They started taking revenge. Now, a dog and his girl are trying to get away--out of New York City, and all the way to San Francisco, to the only person who might be able to protect and save her."_ (seriously, [check it out!](http://aftershockcomics.com/animosity/) It's great! :) ) As for Deacon talking - it's possible. Although why the animals can talk without vocal cords is still a mystery (the animals themselves acknowledge it).